# How to read a BGP table?

Tags: routing, bgp

I have come across BGP looking glass where I can see the routing table for public routers.

Please find below a public entry:

```
BGP routing table entry for 78.97.0.0/16
Versions:
  Process           bRIB/RIB  SendTblVer
  Speaker            1180898     1180898
Last Modified: Dec  5 02:01:10.548 for 7w3d
Paths: (12 available, best #1)
  Advertised IPv4 Unicast paths to update-groups (with more than one peer):
    0.1 0.9 
  Advertised IPv4 Unicast paths to peers (in unique update groups):
    83.217.231.86   91.186.184.10   
  Path #1: Received by speaker 0
  Advertised IPv4 Unicast paths to update-groups (with more than one peer):
    0.1 0.9 
  Advertised IPv4 Unicast paths to peers (in unique update groups):
    83.217.231.86   91.186.184.10   
  6830
    213.46.170.165 (metric 10) from 129.250.0.14 (129.250.0.14)
      Origin IGP, metric 4294967294, localpref 100, valid, confed-internal, best, group-best
      Received Path ID 0, Local Path ID 1, version 1180898
      Community: 2914:390 2914:1210 2914:2210 2914:3200 6830:11000 6830:11101 6830:11102 6830:34001 65504:6830
  Path #2: Received by speaker 0
  Not advertised to any peer
```

What are process, speaker and SendTblVer?

What does 'best #1' mean?

What is 'confed-internal'?

Thanks.

Comment: Which parts are giving you trouble?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaker simply means that your router "speak" in BGP so there is BGP running on your router.

SendTblVer mean that your router send BGP table version 1180898 (its starting from one and rising when changes or new paths are being added). [(If you want to read more)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/116511-technote-tableversion-00.html#anc3)

Best #1 means that out of your 12 possible paths the path that is number (#)1 is the best one and will be used to forward traffic. Sometimes you can see "best #2" and etc. which means other paths are the best.

confed-internal means that BGP peer for this path is considered as internal peer instead of external and you can configure BGP confederation [(more about it here)](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-11844)